# Execute NGUI button press from script in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, ngui

I have a NGUI button and it contains `UIButton` and `UIToggle` script. From another script i want to run its `click` event with all relevant button state changes like colour change etc. For this I found [this link](http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=12495.0) and here is my code.

```
   public UIButton userManagmentBtn;
    public void ClosePanel()
    {
        Debug.Log("Calling panel Colse");
        EventDelegate.Execute(userManagmentBtn.onClick);
    }
```

But the click event is not firing using this: `EventDelegate.Execute`

Answer (score 0):

No NGUI expert but afaik to invoke all listeners you can simply call

```
userManagementBtn.OnClick();
```

Additionally for having the correct coloring etc you could call [`SetState`](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_button.html#aa0ad5ea4590de0b4fad7753579a4f827)

```
userManagementBtn.SetState(UIButtonColor.State.Pressed, true);
```

---

Alternatively you could try and send "manually" the according pointer events via [`ExecuteEvents.Execute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute.html) like e.g.

```
var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
ExecuteEvents.Execute(userManagementBtn.gameObject, pointer, ExecuteEvents.pointerEnterHandler);
ExecuteEvents.Execute(userManagementBtn.gameObject, pointer, ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
```